# Checkbox control from OOXML format getting converted into "?"

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am working on a Word Addin/Office JS Project which deals with Word templates. My requirement is to load the static table into template when the user clicks on the Addin.

Step 1: Converting Static Table Data into OOXML and Storing it into Database.

Sample Table Structure:Image1

[image]

This Table has Check box controls and Content Control inside it.
I am generating OOXML for this loading it into database.

***Code***

```
var body = context.document.body;

var bodyOOXML = body.getOoxml();
```

Step 2: Retrieving the table data from Database and loading it in the document when the user click on the addin.

***Code***

```
 var body = context.document.body;

 body.insertOoxml(currentOOXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
```

but when I retrieving the table data, the check box control in the table are displayed as "?"

Please find the sample below

Sample Table Structure:

[image]

Can some one help me with this: I don’t understand why checkbox controls are getting converted as "?"

If I click on "?" its converting back into a Checkbox

Comment: Could you please tell us the Word UI commands that were used to create these checkboxes? There are at least four different possibilities and without knowing which one this is, it's not possible to research what the problem might be... That, or provide the Word Open XML that defines such a checkbox.

Comment: @CindyMeister  Steps followed to create Checkbox control: Step 1: Open a word document. Step 2:Navigate to the Developers tab. Step 3:Click on check box control   and control is getting added in the document

Comment: My research indicates that the behavior is *probably* due to the Unicode font not being recognized immediately. The Word Open XML reveals that a checkbox content control is Unicode 2610 / 2612 formatted with the font MS Gothic, which is "wrapped" in whichever font applied to the text, otherwise. There's code behind clicking the font symbol that switches between these two Unicode values.The Word Open XML: `<w14:checkbox><w14:checked w14:val="0"/><w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic"/><w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic"/></w14:checkbox>`

Comment: Note that this "code behind" is probably the reason @WenboShi writes that the control is not supported in Word Online.

Comment: You might try a ***form field*** (from the `Legacy Tools` in the same group where the checkbox content control is located) and see if that works any better for you...

Comment: @CindyMeister the existing templates are designed with Check box control, using check box form field changes the layout which is not acceptable. please let us know when we can expect this to fixed from Microsoft end

Comment: <w14:checkbox><w14:checked w14:val="0"/><w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic"/><w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic"/></w14:checkbox> @CindyMeister i am also getting the same xml please let us know whether there is any other option to fix this its not working in both native and online word

Comment: I am ***not** a Microsoft employee nor in any way related to the company. I cannot answer your demands about things getting "fixed". I am a volunteer on Stack Overflow, trying to help you find a *workaround*. Stack Overflow is *not* an official support channel for Microsoft products.

Answer (score 1):

check box control is not supported in Word Online. Only Rich Text Content Control is supported in Word Online.

Comment: Wenbo Shi I tried the same in office 365 word desktop version still facing the same issue.